# Are there any color specifications to follow while designing UI of an android app

Tags: android, user-interface

I am developing an android application and created some image buttons(green coloured) using 'AAA logomaker' software. But the problem is when installing my app in different devices, the intensity of color of the image button is  showing differently.

Are there any color specifications to follow so that the image color appears same in all the devices??

Comment: Those different devices have different types of screen, so the colours look a bit different on each one.  The same is true with computer monitors, take a look at your graphics on different PCs and the colours will be different there too.

Comment: I agree, but take some apps like EVERNOTE. In all the devices, it almost displays the same color intensity. But for the same devices, my button color showing a lot of difference in intensity. May be there will be some specifications like 'density' etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a different button images for different size of devices, like

```
36x36 for low-density
48x48 for medium-density
72x72 for high-density
96x96 for extra high-density
```

Also possible make 9-patch images for buttons..

For more info look at [Icon Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html)

Comment: Yes, your images get blur. the problem you are currently facing.

Comment: I had read these docs, we can specify a size for icon for different densities and resolutions. But what about the buttons created which are rectangular in shape?? I am really worried about the intensity of color only.

Comment: All views graphic design refer same guide line. either its rectangle or circle, Button or any icon image..

Comment: Thanks for the useful info and quick replies.Now i got some clarification about this. Have to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create images for the button like controls, i would suggest you to create it by using [**9-patch**](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) tool which allows you to create [NinePatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html) image actually.

[image]

Comment: 9-patch tool is used for adjusting the image size automatically in different resolutions right?? It maintains the intensity of colors too??

Comment: yes it automatically adjust the size of image based on the screen resolution.